# Proving that a rational sequence is monotonic decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> **Problem 4**. Let $a>0$ be a real number and consider the sequence $(x_n)$ given by $$a_{n+1} = \frac{x_n^2 + a}{2x_n}$$

([original scan of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUPTM.png))

I want to show that this sequence is monotonic decreasing for all $n>2$.

is induction the way to go for this, or something else?

Comment: Consider $x_{n+1} - \sqrt{a}$. Replace $x_{n+1}$ by the right hand side. Simplify.

Comment: will try this now, thank you.

Comment: all i can simplify to is $\large\frac{x_n(x_n-2\sqrt{a}) + a}{2x_n}$ - what am i missing here?

Comment: You wrote it inconveniently. Write the numerator as $$x_n^2 - 2\sqrt{a} x_n + \sqrt{a}^2.$$ Do you see a simplification in that form?

Comment: oh, that is convenient. that is just $(\sqrt{a} - x_n)^2$.

Comment: I'd write it as $(x_n - \sqrt{a})^2$ since $x_n \geqslant \sqrt{a}$ for $n \geqslant 2$. From that it hopefully is easy to see that $x_{n+1} \leqslant x_n$ ($n \geqslant 2$).

Comment: my professor is claiming it's a strict inequality, but it's not is it? if you take $x_1 = \sqrt{a}$ (which is stupid, but you could)

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes, sorry

Comment: It is strict unless $x_1 = \sqrt{a}$ when the sequence is constant (and just for the sake of completeness, undefined if $x_1 = 0$, and increasing if $x_1 < 0$, then it converges to $-\sqrt{a}$).

Comment: @DanielFischer what do I know about $\large \frac{(x_n-\sqrt{a})^2}{2x_n} = x_{n+1}$ that tells me $x_{n+1} < x_n$?

Comment: You forgot a $-\sqrt{a}$, it's $$x_{n+1} - \sqrt{a} = \frac{(x_n-\sqrt{a})^2}{2x_n}.$$ Now, assuming we have started with $x_1 > 0$, that firstly shows that $x_n \geqslant \sqrt{a}$ for $n \geqslant 2$. Then it follows that $\frac{x_n-\sqrt{a}}{2x_n} < \frac12$ for $n \geqslant 2$, and therefore, unless $x_n = \sqrt{a}$, we have $$0 < x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a} = \frac{x_n-\sqrt{a}}{2x_n}\cdot(x_n-\sqrt{a}) < \frac12(x_n - \sqrt{a}).$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$x_{n}-x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2+a}{2x_n}=\frac{x_n^2-a}{2x_n}.$$
So we want to show that $x_n^2\ge a$. This need not be true at $n=1$, but it is true after that. For if $n\gt 1$ then 
$$x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}^2+a}{2x_{n-1}}$$ and therefore 
$$x_n^2-a=\left(\frac{x_{n-1}^2+a}{2x_{n-1}}\right)^2-a=\frac{(x_{n-1}^2-a)^2}{4x_{n-1}^2} $$